# Is it mandatory to travel at least once on Germany Job Seeker Visa

Tags: visas, germany

If I have a Germany Job Seeker Visa which has validity for 6 months. 
Can I extend the validity if I do not travel for a job search.

Or should I reapply again after certain period of time ?

Answer (score 2):

A job seeker visa for Germany cannot be extended.

You have 6 months to either find a job or return to your home country, from where you can apply for a new visa but it will be tougher to obtain.

Normally in order to then get a secondary job seeker visa, you would have to show that you have improved your skills in some way which had previously stopped you obtaining a job.  e.g.  more training, qualifications, or improvement in your German language skills.